# PHP Warning ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied

Tags: php, warnings, permission-denied, php-ziparchive

I created an application, which using method extractTo() in class ZipArchive (standard in php) and I tested it on my localhost apache server on Windows 7 without any problem. But after I tried it on some unix production server, it just throws

```
Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied in /path/to/file.php on line 27
```

I even set chmod on 0777 for every folder which is used by application, but it doesn't help.

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: The script needs to be able to access each parent folder recursively aswell, that doesn't mean 777, more 644.

Comment: Its that is not working with 777, will it work with 644?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the user running Apache (sometimes a user "www-data") has access to the zip file in question.

Also try changing the owner of the file to the user running Apache (check `top` for the user).

Answer (score 17):

For linux / macosx user, change

```
$zip->extractTo('/Directory/');
```

To

```
$zip->extractTo('Directory/');
```

Can help too.

Comment: thank you for sharing this answer - it immediately fixed my issue running ZipArchive from the Linux terminal

Comment: Thanks so much, would've never guessed this!

Comment: Wasted an hour to realize that this might actually work. But why? Path without / implicitly mean root?

Answer (score 0):

this worked on ubuntu server

"sudo chown --recursive www-data:www-data *"