# Strange behaviour when try to extract a zip file in docker container with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, docker, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to extract a zip archive in a docker container app running Laravel 9 on PHP 8.1.7, and i'm facing a weird error.

So if a try this code in a controller

```
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $result = $zip->open("/var/www/html/public/my_archive.zip");
    if ($result === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo("/var/www/html/public/my_folder");
    }
    $zip->close();
```

the files in archive are correctly extracted, but return this error:

**ErrorException**
**ZipArchive::extractTo(/var/www/html/public/my_folder/my_file.xml): Operation failed: Operation not permitted**

If I run the same code in php artisan tinker it works.

Anyone have some idea to fix this problem?

It ***don't seem a permissions related problem***, the folder is created with 777 permission and the files are copied correctly.

**EDIT**

```
  root@5899a5badc45:/var/www/html/public/my_folder# ls -lhart *
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000 1.3K Oct 25 12:24 phpunit.xml
```

Thanks

Comment: Check file permissions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Warning ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446583/php-warning-ziparchiveextractto-permission-denied)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission Denied Error using Laravel & Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619445/permission-denied-error-using-laravel-docker)

Comment: @Justinas the php version is updated 8.1.7

Comment: `docker exec -ti your_image bash`, then copy zip file to folder `/var/www/html/public/my_folder` then `cd /var/www/html/public/my_folder/` and `unzip file.zip`. Does this work ?

Comment: @Niloct Yes in command line works...

Comment: `/var/www/html/public/my_folder/my_file.xml`: seems like the parameter to `extractTo` you're calling is a `file` `my_file.xml` ?... Double-check your source code. The method call should be `$zip->extractTo("/var/www/html/public/my_folder");`, not `$zip->extractTo("/var/www/html/public/my_folder/my_file.xml");`

Comment: the code: $zip->extractTo("/var/www/html/public/my_folder"); 

the error: ZipArchive::extractTo(/var/www/html/public/my_folder/phpunit.xml)

Comment: Hm. Go in `bash` again, `cd` to folder and when issue `ls -lhart *`, please edit your question with the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249039/discussion-between-cesare-and-niloct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encoutered exactly the same problem. On my side I had this issue because I was extracting files in a directory that was mounted from Windows.

I mean `/var//html/public/my_folder` was a symlink of `/mnt/dev/my_folder`, that was coming from Windows (`C:\dev\my_folder` for example).

As filesystem are different from Linux and Windows, it seems like there might be something specific in the ZipArchive class that causes this error.

I fixed it by extracting files in `/tmp/my_folder` then move them to `/var/html/public/my_folder`.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$res = $zip->open($filename);

if ($res === true) {
  $temp = '/tmp/my_folder';
  mkdir($temp, 0777, true);

  $zip->extractTo($temp);
  $zip->close();

  rename($temp, '/var/html/public/my_folder');
} else {
  echo 'Failed to open the zip file.';
}
```

I hope, this gonna be helpful.